# sshd_config: disabled PasswordAuthentication and lost private key

Tags: security, ssh

that's only hypothetical question, it hasn't happened to me (yet).

I want to configure secure ssh on my VPS.
I'm going to use a public/private key pair (with passphrase) to authentication and I'm also going to set PasswordAuthentication to "no".

The question is:
Would I be able to restore access to my VPS via SSH if I lost my private key?

On a desktop it rather wouldn't be a problem, but is it possible on any VPS accessible only via SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your VPS has a "out of band console" you will can log in the system like a local user.

Ask your provider for this facility.

Comment: I thought about this workaround and it seems to be the only possible way to achieve this (except for reinstalling vps' OS or at least submitting ticket to a VPS provider)

Comment: Or change the config file in the panel if you have a VPS+panel installation. You only need write /etc/sshd_config.